# JavaScript Angular 1.5.x Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

When learning Angular 1.5, I got really confused about the usage of the tags.

Namely, I can't understand why there needs to be a 'global' object to contain the variables within a controller.

JS Bin : http://jsbin.com/puyayocomi/11/edit?html,js,output

**The question is** : *Why can't we call variables directly created within the controller instead of using a global object( in this case called 'namespace' )to hold all the controller variables?*

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2> Angular Controllers </h2>

        <!-- Why not : ng-controller="todoCtrl" -->
        <div ng-controller="todoCtrl as namespace">
        <!--                                    -->    
            <ul class="unstyled">
                <!-- Why not : ng-repeat="todo in todos" -->
                <li ng-repeat="todo in namespace.todos">
                <!--                                     -->
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                        <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}. </span>
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript :

```
console.log( 'Hello Script!' );

angular.module( 'todoApp',[] ).controller( 'todoCtrl',function()
{
    var namespace = this;

    namespace.todos =
    [
    { text:'one', done:true },
    { text:'two', done:false }
    ];

    /* 
    <!-- Why not : -->

    var todos =
    [
    { text:'one', done:true },
    { text:'two', done:false }
    ];
    */
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way, pass the $scope variable to your function controller and it will give you a namespace that the html looks in for your variables.

[JS Bin Here](http://jsbin.com/fonemawami/edit?html,js,output)

HTML

```
    <div ng-controller="todoCtrl">
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                    <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

JavaScript :

```
angular.module( 'todoApp',[] ).controller( 'todoCtrl',function( $scope )
{    
    $scope.todos =
    [
      { text:'one', done:true },
      { text:'two', done:false }
    ];
})
```

Comment: `$scope.todos` and `this.todos` are equivalent - john papa's angular styleguide favors `this` - see https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y031

Answer (score 3):

It basically comes down to how function scopes work in JavaScript:

```js
function Controller() {
  // local variable
  var foo = 1;

  // instance property
  this.bar = 2;
}

// imagine Angular creates an instance of your controller like this:
var instance = new Controller();
console.log('foo', instance.foo) // undefined
console.log('bar', instance.bar) // 2
```

So, in short: Local variables can not be accessed from outside the function, while properties bound to `this` can.

Comment: You're welcome! I guess it also makes sense this way, because like this you're more explicit about what you really want in the view vs. what is just a temporary variable.

Comment: Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If i answered your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark icon ;)